# How do import and save term lineage using feeds and Hierarchical select?

Tags: feeds, taxonomy-terms

I have to import a number of nodes that only has the lowest term in the csv

e.g. Washington

However, in the taxonomy hierarchy it has United States > Washington

I am using the [Hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module for saving the term lineage however when I use feeds it tries to import the child term as the parent term and doesn't actually select anything.

How do I use feeds and Hierarchical select to import just the child term but save the entire lineage?

The closest I can come to is https://www.drupal.org/node/1319278 however the csv mush contain the lineage, whereas in this case we only have the lowest possible child term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and testing decided to use the [Term Set Lineage module](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_set_lineage) so that it is set on import, then just changed to use the Hierarchical select module.